# How to write fallible nom parsers

Tags: rust, nom

If I want to write a nom parser that could fail internally, how do I propagate the error?

As an example, something to parse a [`NaiveDate`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDate.html) might look like:

```rust
fn parse_date(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, NaiveDate> {
    map(take(10), |s| NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s, "%m/%d/%Y")?)(i)
}
```

The [`parse_from_str`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDate.html#method.parse_from_str) may fail and returns its own [`ParseResult`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/type.ParseResult.html) type.

I actually rely on it's success/failure to determine if this parser works.

How can I convert an inner Result (in this case `chrono::format::ParseResult`) to something that works with nom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Nom's [`map_res`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.1/nom/combinator/fn.map_res.html) method. MapRes emits only the `ErrorKind::MapRes` (no custom error), but if only ok/err result is needed that should suffice.

```rust
use chrono::NaiveDate;
use nom::bytes::streaming::take;
use nom::combinator::map_res;
use nom::error::{Error, ErrorKind};
use nom::IResult;

fn parse_date(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, NaiveDate> {
    map_res(take(10usize), |s| NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s, "%m/%d/%Y"))(i)
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        parse_date("01/31/2022: rest").unwrap(),
        (": rest", NaiveDate::from_ymd(2022, 01, 31))
    );

    assert_eq!(
        parse_date("yy/xx/2022").unwrap_err(),
        nom::Err::Error(Error::new("yy/xx/2022", ErrorKind::MapRes))
    );
}
```